# Why does the index page don't appear when entering the url after launching the app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

Guys I have cloned a spring boot project but every time I try to launch the app and enter the url for the index page it give me alot of errors
the url is 127.0.0.1:8070

I tried to change the dependencies but the problem continues , please if anyone can helps or have a solution i would appreciate it

the error shown in the terminal is : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()'

and here are the dependencies of the App:

```
<dependencies>
    

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.24</version>
        </dependency>


        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.8</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

here is the project link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_UhYiPaBKfaARj1ZIA8JLFKSP5-8aOfP/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Please put the necessary details to reproduce the problem in the question itself rather than providing a link to it.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian The problem seems to be with the dependencies or the configuration that's why I added the link to the project also the error shown in the terminal is : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()'

Comment: Again, put such details in the question. As it is written the question runs a high risk of getting closed and not receiving any attention. The detail/exception you added in your comment is a great example of something that should be part of the question but it is not limited to that. 
Read more about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DanielBarbarian Thank you for your advice. I have edited the question and added more details check it now and till me if it need more details.

Comment: The most likely reason is that you have two versions of `HttpServletMapping` on your classpath. Do you need to have `javax.servlet-api` dependency explicitly defined considering you already have all the spring boot stuff there? What happens when you try to remove that dependency?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian If I removed the javax.servlet-api  I will get the the same error there is no Change :  Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()'] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletMapping javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()'